# How to type greek letters and equations into evernote or any other OSX application

Tags: macos, evernote, equations

How can I type greek letters and mathematical equations into Evernote or any other OSX application?

Comment: Evernote doesn't behave differently from other applications in Mac OS X in this regard. You can safely remove all references to it from your question to make it more useful to others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some might be available on your keyboard. Some might need to be inserted e.g. using Character Viewer.

Open *System Preferences » Keyboard* and check *Show Keyboard & Character Viewer in menu bar*.

You'll have a new status item to the right of the menu bar. From there, you can open the following:

- Keyboard Viewer lets you see all the characters you can press using your current keyboard layout. Press modifier keys (*option* and/or *shift*) to see which characters you type when these modifier keys are pressed. Pressing `w` while holding down *option* results in ∑ for me.
  [image]
- Character Viewer shows you all (?) characters available on your system. Select a character and click *Insert*, or double-click the character to insert it in your current text box.
  [image]

Comment: Every time I check the "Show Keyboard & Character Viewer" and I close the "system preferences" window, nothing shows up on my menu bar and if I reopen the System preferences, the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: @Fernando If you have multiple keyboard layouts ("input sources") defined, they share a menu item. Otherwise, go to *System Preferences » Language & Text » Input Sources* and make sure *Show input menu in menu bar* is checked.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Input Sources menu item in your menu bar, you can switch to a Greek keyboard layout. Then, you can just type without the Option key and you have access to the full alphabet.

Comment: Might be inconvenient if just required for a handful of mathematical symbols, but could be useful anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the complexity of your equations it might also be an idea to have a look at LaTeX and in specific the free application [LaTeXiT](http://www.chachatelier.fr/programmation/latexit_en.php) which can provide a system-wide shortcut (via the "services" menu) to typeset formulas though LaTeX and insert them e.g. as a PDF.

This has been a lifesaver for me when I had to typeset sophisticated equations into Keynote and PowerPoint presentations!

Answer (score 0):

CajunLuke mentioned the input sources menu. Once you've selected the Greek keyboard in that menu, you can go to the preferences screen Keyboard>Shortcuts and assign a custom shortcut to switch input sources. It makes throwing a few greek letters into a sentence very quick and easy, once you've learned which keys map to which characters -- no need to open a viewer window or bring in the mouse. Just hit the shortcut, type in Greek, and hit it again to switch back.

However, be careful to make your shortcut a non-letter key (e.g., ctrl-shift-space). If you use a letter, it will be recognized when you switch from your normal language to Greek, but it won't be recognized when you want to switch back.